# BASH: trying to read in file but it only gets the first line

Tags: linux, bash, file

Im trying to read in a file in bash and store the variables to be used at some later point, the format for the files is as follows

name abbreviation

price quantity maxQuantitiy

itemDescription

but when i try to  actually read in the file it seems ot only store the first line in every variable and was wondering where it is that its storing the variables wrong

```
if [ -r data/$fileName.file ]; then
    read name abbreviation < data/$fileName.file
    read price quantity maxQuantity < data/$fileName.file
    read itemDescription < data/$fileName.file
fi
```

and when i try to echo the price or quantity it echos the name and the abbreviation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read` reads the first line. When you do another redirection, it's not tied to the previous one, so it again reads the first line. You need to use **one** redirection for all the reads:

```
if [ -r data/$fileName.file ]; then
    {
        read name abbreviation
        read price quantity maxQuantity
        read itemDescription
    } < data/$fileName.file
fi
```